# Align All Elements in One Horizontal Row in Twitter Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm encountering issues keeping all 3 components of the Bootstrap-based `navbar` in one horizontal row. This navbar has **fluid width**.

**Question:** How can we tweak the code to get all the 3 items (from left to right: `a`, `form` and `ul`) to be arrange in one line? The `form` should take 100% of the space remaining betweem the orange color `a` and the Login/Signup `ul`.

**Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/oEkHN0DVmE

**Currently**

[image]

**Desired**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <a class="brand" href="#">
        <img src="/img/logo-white.png">
    </a>

    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal search-form">        
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-search"></i> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </form>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/users/sign_in">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.brand {
    width: 170px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fc4310;
    display: inline-block
}

.search-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Enclose `a` and `form` tags in `ul` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply:

```
nav { display: flex; }
```

That aligns all nav child elements in a single row.

For spacing the elements on the row, see options here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Answer (score 1):

Did some changes to your code...

I hope this will help you..

refer this **[demo](http://www.bootply.com/G5aT5nrTDZ)**

added navigation header

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/100x50"></a>
    </div>
```

and change the form little bit with css

```
<form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="fill">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"><span class="btn"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.fill {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.fill .form-control {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}


.fill .btn {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:1%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.navbar-brand{
    padding:0;
    margin-right:15px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the gird sistem:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a class="brand" href="#">
        <img src="/img/logo-white.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal search-form">        
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-search"></i> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/users/sign_in">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/rV9ZF8sO7N

Answer (score 0):

Change some css

```
  .search-form {
      width: 83%;
      height: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
 .search-form input{margin-top:35px}
 .nav.navbar-nav{margin-top:25px;}
```

http://www.bootply.com/YFnjNIZ7Wo